# DQL complicated Query

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

Ok I have 2 tables, the relevant structure is the following:

```
**youtubevideo**
id - int
allViews - relational


**views**
id - int
youtubevideo_id - int
viewCount - int
firstFetch - date
```

Its relevant that youtubevideo has many views. This is presented by a OneToMany in a Symfony entity.

Now, I have 2 dates, lets call them fromDate and toDate. I need to select all youtubevideos and order them by the viewCount sum of the views that belong to them.

And I only want to use the views that have their firstFetch date, between the fromDate and the toDate.

So I imagine it would be something like

```
SELECT y FROM YTScraperBundle:YouTubeVideo y 
JOIN y.allViews v GROUP BY y.id 
ORDER BY SUM(v.viewCount) LIMIT 0, 30; <-- or does this need to be an inline select to the specific element?
```

And I don't really see how to put WHERE v.firstFetch is between fromDate and toDate in there.

**UPDATE**

```
$query = $this->em->createQuery(
    "SELECT y, IF(v IS NULL, 0, SUM(v.viewCount)) AS HIDDEN sumviewcount
    FROM YTScraperBundle:YouTubeVideo y
    LEFT JOIN y.allViews v WITH v.firstFetch BETWEEN :fromDate AND :toDate
    GROUP BY y ORDER BY sumviewcount DESC
    "
);
$query->setMaxResults(self::PR_PAGE);
$query->setFirstResult($firstResult);
$query->setParameter('fromDate', $fromDate);
$query->setParameter('toDate', $toDate);
```

Getting the error:

```
Expected known function, got 'IF'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `WITH`, `BETWEEN`, and bind two `DateTime` objects into a parameterized query:

```
$result = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->createQuery('
    SELECT y, 
        CASE WHEN (v IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE SUM(v.viewCount) END AS HIDDEN sumviewcount
    FROM YTScraperBundle:YouTubeVideo y 
    LEFT JOIN y.allViews v WITH v.firstFetch BETWEEN :fromDate AND :toDate
    GROUP BY y ORDER BY sumviewcount DESC
')->setParameter('fromDate', new \DateTime('12-34-5678 00:00:00')) // Replace this with an ISO date
->setParameter('toDate', new \DateTime('12-34-5678 00:00:00')) // Replace here too
->getResult();
```

I've [combined @Matteo's answer concerning the `SUM` into mine for posterity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26846879/1188035). Credit goes to him for the `HIDDEN` idea.

Comment: I am having an issue with this returning 1 row, also, it should still get the youtubevideos even if they have 0 views associated, the views should just not be attached to it, if that makes sense :)

Comment: @IvanRistic Let's tackle the 0 views issue first and see if it solves the 0-row problem. `JOIN` defaults to `INNER JOIN` so we have to explicitly call `LEFT JOIN`. See my edit. Note that `v.viewCount` would be `NULL` on empty joins so this could create another problem...

Comment: Now i am getting a very odd issue, sorting behaving very odd, not working, and date is not filtering:

        $query = $this->em->createQuery(
            "SELECT y, SUM(v.viewCount) AS HIDDEN sumviewcount
            FROM YTScraperBundle:YouTubeVideo y
            LEFT JOIN y.allViews v WITH v.firstFetch BETWEEN :fromDate AND :toDate
            GROUP BY y ORDER BY sumviewcount DESC
            "
        );

Comment: @IvanRistic Update your question with your full code including the `setParameter` functions. I've made an edit to my answer to handle the `NULL` values for `y.allViews` as well... try that out but it won't solve everything yet

Comment: Updated :) Thanks for helping btw

Comment: Woops, sorry pasted a parameter that was not used, updated again

Comment: Seems like IF is not usable in DQL and case should be used

Comment: @IvanRistic Yeah I saw that and already updated my question to use `CASE`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64645/discussion-between-sjagr-and-ivan-ristic).

Comment: I think its working, but the issue seems to be that i am still including all views in my YouTubeVideo element, one moment and i will test, so its sorting them correctly, but everything is returned, so the values are still off, anyway 1 sec :)

Answer (score 2):

For sorting, you can use the `HIDDEN` Doctrine2 features (available since Doctrine 2.2+).

```
SELECT y, 
       SUM(v.viewCount) AS HIDDEN sumviewcount 
FROM YTScraperBundle:YouTubeVideo y 
JOIN y.allViews v  
GROUP BY y
ORDER BY sumviewcount 
LIMIT 0, 30;
```

Take a look at [this](http://michelsalib.com/2012/03/04/doctrine2-ninja-with-the-hidden-keyword/) article.

Hope this help

Comment: For some reason this only returns one row

Comment: sorry my pseudocode try removing the `distinct` statement or add `group by y`

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This works for the views, now i will just try to implement the BETWEEN Clause :) !

Comment: for date between clausole you can use the one in the @sjagr answer, what do you change in my solution for make it work? So i will fix it... :)

Comment: SELECT y, SUM(v.viewCount) AS HIDDEN sumviewcount FROM YTScraperBundle:YouTubeVideo y JOIN y.allViews v group by y ORDER BY sumviewcount DESC

Comment: +1 I've integrated your answer into mine for completeness/posterity